# Back button when pagination is used in table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

In my angular js application i am using pagination in user list page,through which i am getting ten users at a time from server,and clicking on second page another ten users and so on.Details of a users are listed in a table.Now when  click on some user,profile of a selected user is open in another page. Now when i come back from user profile to user list my table is again start from current page one.
That's the issue i want when i come back from user profile , user list must be open from the page where i was.

Comment: Read about [$location.search](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) to set the current page in the URL and how to read the property when you go back to the state

Answer (score 0):

There are some way that you can fix it.
I recommend you two way.

**First:**
Change hash in your url when your table page changed and detect hash when you come back to your page.
like this url

> http://youraddress.com/subdirs#page=2

You can find how change and detect hash in this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

**Second:**
Open user page in ajax div with $http in angularJS.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http